# Magento how to forced change order status to processing after creating shipment?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, zend-framework

How to forced change order status to processing after creating shipment ? On the magento default the order status always change to complete when shipment is created. Here is the step by step scenario:

1) When order is pending upon creating shipment the order status will change to processing.

2) When order is in processing upon creating shipment the order status will change to complete.

So what I want is when order is in processing upon creating shipment the order status will **NOT** change to complete and I want the order to be still in processing.

What would be the best solution for this? Is anyone know how to solve this ?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you give a little explanation why you want this behavior? Its actually not so easy, and also depends on shipping/payment modules, which can change this.
Also, which action should change the state later to complete?

Answer (score 1):

Thats kind of a hard thing you want to archive there.

The problem is, after the shipping got created, the order calculates the order status new (some of this happens in Model_Order->_checkState() ) so regardless what you set in the after shipping save event, it gets overwritten.

The Question becomes, why it is important to not have the state complete after this.

A possible Solution would be, to have a different complete status, which you can make the default, so you always have to set the complete/complete separate.
But this maybe does not fit your needs.